# How to disable edit functionality for my mimetype for non-creator

Tags: google-drive-api

For my application, I cannot let people who are not the creator of the content edit it.  Viewing is fine.

Is there is way to disable the "Can edit" and "Is owner" options inside Sharing settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is:

- An account in your control actually owns the file.
- The user that creates the doc gets read access in Google Drive.
- Your application tracks which user "created" the document on it's own.
- Document creators are able to edit the doc inside your app although your app is actually using your own account which owns the file to save changes.